# A new flag: "not-constructive"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging

Many a times, there are questions which are absolutely vague and have no meaning in them, like: [If I fall from a great height, will I overcome the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/352263/if-you-fall-for-a-long-enough-period-of-time-would-you-eventually-hit-or-break)

Now, these are off topic questions, but there are no proper flags for this. Generally I flag this as very low quality, but many times, why I don't know, this flag is not available after one close vote has been submitted.

These are not homework questions or do not satisfy any other realm of flagging. So, there should be a proper flag as "not-constructive", so that these off topic questions can stand out, and can be properly flagged.

One can close with a custom close reason, but in case of flagging, only option is to call for Moderator Intervention, but I don't feel such questions are of a minimum quality to call for Moderator Intervention, and disturb them everytime.

The "unclear what you're asking" flag is not a good option, because it is very clear what the asker wants to know,  but the question is foolish and has no dedicated answer.

So, there should be a separate flag called "not-constructive", and a separate review queue to handle them.

Comment: I request down voters to please indicate the reason of not supporting.

Comment: I do not support because it isn't necessary at all.  This question in particular doesn't even really seem _that bad_.  If it were not a duplicate, I don't even agree that it really warrants a close.  Perhaps a downvote due to lack of research and somewhat unclear question (due to lack of detail).  I wouldn't call the question "non-constructive" though.  It's a valid question with a significant answer.

Comment: That question is an example only.

Comment: It seemed like a poor example.  Either way, "non-constructive" seems pretty much the same as "not useful", which is cited as a reason to downvote when you hover over the button, not a close reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- If it's vague, flag/vote to close as Unclear What You're Asking.
- If you think it should be closed but none of the canned reasons fit, then flag/vote to close with a custom reason. If five 3k+ users agree with you, then it will get closed. If not, then it will get kicked out of the close-vote review queue and the question likely shouldn't be closed.
- If it is a bad question but it doesn't fit the requirements for closure, then downvote, leave a comment explaining why the question is bad if you want to, and move on. There's better things to do in life than obsess over how to handle marginal edge cases of bad questions on some site on the internet.